# Move View up down with click on EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-animation

i have a registration screen (which is a relative layout having multiple EditText and a Button) and i simply want my View to move up and down smoothly with click on each EditText so none of the EditText stay hidden behind the Keyboard.

At the moment the Bottom Editview is hiding behind the keyboard.

I tried 'adjustResize'  but rather than moving the whole view up/down, its only moving the bottom Button up/down.

**Screen1:**

[image]

**Screen After "adjustResize"**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just add

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` is manifest file.

Also put your layout in the `ScrollView` so you can scroll your layout while the keyboard is on.

Comment: There's no need to put layout in scrollview